# How can I capture statistics of a .aspx web page before the user closes the page?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am developing an asp.net web page which features a video the user watches. I am trying to capture statistics of how far the user watched the video. Getting the numbers is no problem at all. The problem is when they close the browser. I need to know how far in the video the user has watched at the time the browser was closed.

---

**JavaScript**

For my Javascript, I created a button that when it is clicked, it will call a server-side function in the .aspx.cs file. The JavaScript code is below. It runs fine everytime the user exits the webpage.

```
window.onbeforeunload = submitStat;

function submitStat() {

        //Get video time
        statString = getCurrentVideoTime();

        //Put the video time into a textbox that the server-side function can read.
        $('#videoStatsText').val(statString);

        //Click the button that calls the server-side function
        document.getElementById("submitVidStat").click();
}
```

---

**HTML**

I have created the button that calls the server-side function, and I have created a text box that the server can read.

```
<asp:Button ID="submitVidStat" Text="Submit Stat" runat="server"  OnClick="submitStat_Click" />
```

---

**C# Server-Side Function**

I have the final function in the C# code that reads the video statistics (from the HTML text box above) and inserts it into the db.

```
protected void submitStat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    submitVidStats();
}

private void submitVidStats()
{
    string stats = videoStatsText.Text;

    //function that inserts the statistics into the database.
    insertVidStats(stats);    
}
```

---

**The Problem**

When I run this on my localhost, it works fine. I can even put breakpoints and I can see the breakpoints being hit even when my browser is closed (because of the window.onbeforeunload JavaScript function). But the problem is when it is in production. When I deploy it to an online server, the statistics never get entered into the database when I look through it. I have no way of knowing whether the server-side code even got called because I can't put breakpoints in production mode. Please help.

Comment: Depending on your server, you can remotely attach the debugger and use breakpoints. But even if you can't, you can add logging to your website.

Comment: You can also check the IIS logs to see if the endpoint got hit.